# Help solving a basic polynomial problem

Tags: polynomials

$(3x-1)^7=a_7x^7+a_6x^6+a_5x^5+...+a_1x+a_0$

Now it is required to find the value of $a_7+a_6+a_5+...+a_1+a_0$

Please give me some hints to solve this problem.Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What happens if you substitute $x$ by $1$?

Comment: @Batominovski-Thanks a lot....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put x=1 , 128 is your answer $2^7$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $$(3x-1)^7=a_7x^7+a_6x^6+a_5x^5+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$$
Now, setting $x=1$ in both the sides, we get

$$(3\times 1-1)^7=a_7(1)^7+a_6(1)^6+a_5(1)^5+\ldots+a_1(1)+a_0$$
$$(2)^7=a_7+a_6+a_5+\ldots+a_1+a_0$$ 
$$\implies a_7+a_6+a_5+\ldots+a_1+a_0=2^7=128$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that (a+b)(c+d) = ac+ad+bc+bd and that n^x * n^y = n^(x+y).

(3x-1)^7 = (3x-1)^2 * (3x-1)^2 * (3x-1)^2 * (3x-1)

Comment: You could do that, sure, but it would be very tedious. A far more efficient solution has already been posted more than half a day before yours.